# Why I get "Your clock is behind" error and how to enable it for my website?

Tags: google-chrome

Why do I get this error when I visit medium.com but not other websites:

> [image]

Yeah I know my system time is incorrect but why I don't get the same error when I go to other websites? Is that something that I can enable for my website? If yes how?

Comment: If your machine thinks it’s Oct 22 that was two days ago and thus incorrect

Comment: Yeah I know it's incorrect. My question was why I get the error on some sites but not all.

Comment: Likely has something to do with Cloudfare. Honestly, there isn't enough information to answer your question.  Since you know the clock is incorrect.  There isn't much purpose in submitting an answer that indicates that is the case. Questions about website(s) are strictly out of scope.

Comment: As [this posted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1749196/167207) states, this is an issue with your web browser comparing timestamps with the new certificate on Medium with your own system’s time. So you are currently experiencing it with Medium, but if any other site you visit has a certificate renewal and your system’s clock is off, this will happen again. The best solution is to fix the time sync on your system. But this makes no sense, “…and how to enable it for my website?” Do you mean “…and how to fix it for my web browser?” Because Medium is not your website, right?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thank you for the response. I found this error when I was searching for a way to check if the system clock of the users is correct (my website would have some problems when the user's clock is not correct) and I thought this is somehow a built-in feature of the browser or something. So I was looking for a way to enable it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a temporal Issue : you are seeing it because [Medium](https://medium.com) has got a new SSL Certificate.

[image: MEDIUM VALIDITY]

**Your Date (Oct 22) is before that Certificate becomes valid (Oct 24) which is the Core Issue.**

That is why you are getting the "Clock Is Behind" Warning.

Wait for 1 week and try again, it will not show the Issue even though your clock is out of sync.